# adjusting the xy axis in asp.net point chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-charts

How do you adjust the formatting of the asp.net point chart? I'd like to dynamically set maximum and minimums based on data in a List<>. I'd also like to figure out the properties that allows me to tweak the intervals within each of the axes and also formatting the labels so that I can change decimals to percentages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to the setting maximum and minimum on the axes. See below:

```
<asp:Chart runat="server" ID="Chart1" Width="500px" Height="500px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" MarkerSize="10" ChartType="Point">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" BorderDashStyle="Solid"
            BackSecondaryColor="White" BackColor="Gainsboro" ShadowColor="Transparent" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom">
            <Area3DStyle Rotation="10" Perspective="10" Inclination="15" IsRightAngleAxes="False"
                WallWidth="0" IsClustered="False" />
            <AxisY LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64">
                <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
            </AxisY>
            <AxisX LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64">
                <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
            </AxisX>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

//define chart UI
            double minimum = -0.08;
            double maximum = 0.08;
            double interval = maximum/2;

```
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = minimum;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = minimum;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = maximum;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = maximum;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = interval;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = interval;
```

However, is there a way to change the label formatting to percentages instead of decimals?